# How to apply changes to the standby database in Oracle dataguard without using the commit command

Tags: oracle, dataguard

I have setup a data guard on two separate servers (primary and standby).
All the steps have been completed and when I make a change in the primary database and commit, it is also applied to the standby server.
Now I want it to be OK without committing the changes on the standby server.
For example, if a record is inserted in the primary database table, that record will also be inserted in the standby database table and there is no need to commit.

I have not found a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. An uncommitted change isn't visible to any other session on the primary; why (and how) would it be visible to any session on the standby?

Answer (score 0):

Lets put aside the standby for a second. If you make a change on a database and commit it, that the change is now there permanently. If you do not commit, it can be considered as never happened, ie, you rolled it back, or not yet happened  (the transaction is open).

Having a standby or not does not impact this fundamental premise.